# Mad Mimi Error When Trying to Send Email to a List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, external, mailer

I am trying to get my Rails Application integrated with Mad Mimi to send out e-mails. Using the API which can be found at https://madmimi.com/developer/mailer/send-to-a-list?escape=false

Here is what I put into the ruby emulator on my terminal:

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'promotion_name' => 'bulletin',     'subject' =>     'Your Daily Bulletin Update', 'from' => 'noreply@matsu-    namibiaflood.opensciencedatacloud.org/', 'list_name' => 'bulletin')
```

Here is what was the result

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `uri' for main:Object
from (irb):8
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What should I do, and should I be putting this code somewhere else?

Comment: so where did you define `uri`?

Comment: uri = URI('https://api.madmimi.com/mailer/to_list')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'promotion_name' => 'bulletin', 'subject' => 'Your Daily Bulletin Update', 'from' => 'noreply@matsu-namibiaflood.opensciencedatacloud.org/', 'list_name' => 'bulletin')

Comment: I tried the above as well and it gave me                                       Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to specify the `uri`, because it is a simple varible. So, if you need to use post-request to some url - you need to put your addres as first parameter at this method.